# When dealing with `bad history file syntax` error, what should I do?

Tags: database, time-series, iotdb

When I started Version 1.2.1 of Apache IoTDB on the client side, then a warning popped out with the information: `WARNING: Failed to load history java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad history file syntax! The history file "/home/pi/.iotdb history-1505998205-6667-3586402'may bean older history`. Can I delete this history file from the directory to deal with this warning? I want to know are there any other things I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly delete your histroy file from the corresponding directory of Apache IoTDB to solve this problem. There is nothing more that you need to do.